# How to insert url link inside a pygame

Tags: python, hyperlink, pygame

Can I add a link into a Pygame? Like in HTML; once it was clicked, we will be redirected to the URL.
I have the game 'Turn Based Battle' -> https://www.pygame.org/project/5492/7939
I want to add a text somewhere on the screen with the link they can press on.
If you want to look at the code you can check on the Github page from the creator, it's basically the same like the game I have now. -> https://github.com/russs123/Battle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is check if the mouse press event happened inside the text's rect. Then you can use `webbrowser.open()` to open the link in a browser.

Sample Code:

```py
import pygame
import webbrowser

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))

link_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 50)
link_color = (0, 0, 0)

running = True

while running:

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    
    rect = screen.blit(link_font.render("Sample Link", True, link_color), (50, 50))

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = event.pos

            if rect.collidepoint(pos):
                webbrowser.open(r"https://stackoverflow.com/")

    if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        link_color = (70, 29, 219)

    else:
        link_color = (0, 0, 0)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.